How to store chlorella for a long time at room temperature?
Is it possible to store chlorella for a long time (6 months) at room temperature? I was thinking about desiccation and looked for some studies on it, but I only found this study (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168945298000557), which is about a specific strain.
